# how to change content of <i class"material-icons> as it was a <p>

Tags: javascript, html, google-fonts

I'm trying to change the buttons of an audio using google icon font but innerHTML is only for paragraph how would you code this in javascript ?

```
if(aud1){
        document.getElementById("play1").addEventListener("click",
            function(){
                if(aud1.paused){
                    aud1.play();
                    document.getElementById("play1").innerHTML = <i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i>;}
                else{
                    aud1.pause();
                    document.getElementById("play1").innerHTML = <i class="material-icons">pause</i>;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign id to your  tag

```
<i id="icon" class="material-icons">play_arrow</i>
```

then change the inner HTML of the  tag

```
if(aud1){
    document.getElementById("play1").addEventListener("click",
        function(){
            if(aud1.paused){
                aud1.play();
                document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML ="play_arrow";}
            else{
                aud1.pause();
                document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML ="pause";
            }
        );
```